# Summing values across each row as boolean (PySpark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I currently have a PySpark dataframe that has many columns populated by integer counts. Many of these columns have counts of zero. **I would like to find a way to sum how many columns have counts greater than zero**.

In other words, I would like an approach that sums values across a row, where all the columns for a given row are effectively boolean (although the datatype conversion may not be necessary). Several columns in my table are datetime or string, so ideally I would have an approach that first selects the numeric columns.

**Current Dataframe example and Desired Output**

```
+---+---------- +----------+------------            
|USER|   DATE   |COUNT_COL1| COUNT_COL2|...     DESIRED COLUMN
+---+---------- +----------+------------ 
| b | 7/1/2019 |  12      |     1     |              2        (2 columns are non-zero)
| a | 6/9/2019 |  0       |     5     |              1
| c | 1/1/2019 |  0       |     0     |              0
```

**Pandas:** As an example, in pandas this can be accomplished by selecting the numeric columns,converting to bool and summing with the axis=1. I am looking for a PySpark equivalent.

```
test_cols=list(pandas_df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.values)
pandas_df[test_cols].astype(bool).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: try something like: `df.withColumn('cnt', sum((df[c[0]]>0).astype("int") for c in df.dtypes if c[1] in ['int','long'])).show()`. you can extend the list to include double, float etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For numericals*, you can do it by creating an **`array`** of all the columns with the **`integer values`**(using **`df.dtypes`**), and then use **`higher order functions`**. In this case I used **`filter`** to get rid of all 0s, and then used size to get the number of all non zero elements per row.**`(spark2.4+)`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("arr", F.array(*[F.col(i[0]) for i in df.dtypes if i[1] in ['int','bigint']]))\
  .withColumn("DESIRED COLUMN", F.expr("""size(filter(arr,x->x!=0))""")).drop("arr").show()

#+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
#|USER|    DATE|COUNT_COL1|COUNT_COL2|DESIRED COLUMN|
#+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
#|   b|7/1/2019|        12|         1|             2|
#|   a|6/9/2019|         0|         5|             1|
#|   c|1/1/2019|         0|         0|             0|
#+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Works well and handles spark dataframes with timestamps/dates. Thanks

Comment: glad to help.thanks @jxc for the tip to use df.schema

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have below df:

```
df.show()
df.printSchema()

+---+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  1|  2|  3|
|  a|  0|  2|  1|
|  a|  0|  0|  1|
|  a|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+

root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
```

Using case when statement you can check if column is numeric and then if it is larger than 0. In the next step `f.size` will return count thanks to `f.array_remove` which left only cols with `True` value.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
cols = [f.when(f.length(f.regexp_replace(f.col(x), '\\d+', '')) > 0, False).otherwise(f.col(x).cast('int') > 0) for x in df2.columns]
df.select("*", f.size(f.array_remove(f.array(*cols), False)).alias("count")).show()

+---+---+---+---+-----+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|count|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
|  a|  1|  2|  3|    3|
|  a|  0|  2|  1|    2|
|  a|  0|  0|  1|    1|
|  a|  0|  0|  0|    0|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: This code seems to have a problem with timestamp columns, which should not be summed. The particular exception is :
```org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;(t1.`date` &gt; 0)&#39; due to data type mismatch: differing types in &#39;(t1.`date` &gt; 0)&#39; (timestamp and int).;;```

Comment: Right, I've made correction and it works with date and timestamp types. My solution will be useful if your dataframe is loaded without inferSchema with all String typed columns.